# How to launch ray tune with poetry on workers

Tags: amazon-web-services, ray

What's the secret to getting ray workers to run within a certain directory, and within a certain virtual environment? I have the feeling I'm missing something fundamental:

I want to run ray tune for hyperparameter tuning (using aws). When I launch the head (and workers), I want to run ray from within a virtual machine (poetry, in my case). It just doesn't work at all. I tried:

```
setup_commands: 
    - cd /home/ubuntu/myimportantdirectory 
    - poetry shell
```

But then I get

```
2020-02-25 17:34:28,592 INFO updater.py:256 -- NodeUpdater: i-0893fd1914fd8743e: Running cd /home/ubuntu/myimportantdirectory on 18.207.133.151...
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

... which I guess means it fails, because then poetry fails with `could not find a pyproject.toml file in /home/ubuntu or its parents`

I also tried

```
setup_commands: 
    - cd /home/ubuntu/myimportantdirectory 
    - . path/to/poetry/activate
```

But then I get `Command 'ray' not found`, even though I'm certain it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. But there's gotta be a better way. Also I can't believe this isn't documented. In the yaml, do this:

```
head_start_ray_commands:
    - . /home/ubuntu/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/robotics-7LCEAdjK-py3.6/bin/activate; ray stop
    - ulimit -n 65536; . /home/ubuntu/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/robotics-7LCEAdjK-py3.6/bin/activate; ray start --head --redis-port=6379 --object-manager-port=8076 --autoscaling-config=~/ray_bootstrap_config.yaml

worker_start_ray_commands:
    - . /home/ubuntu/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/robotics-7LCEAdjK-py3.6/bin/activate; ray stop
    - ulimit -n 65536; . /home/ubuntu/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/robotics-7LCEAdjK-py3.6/bin/activate; ray start --redis-address=$RAY_HEAD_IP:6379 --object-manager-port=8076
```